Trying to add multiple lists to a nested dictionary, but its skipping the first list
def getEntries():
    # Loop variables, etc
    loopNum = 1
    setupString = ''
    entryData = []

    # Loop will go through all our entry boxes in our grid
    # For each row, we will get the data and build our string and then append it to
    for entry in my_entries:
        if loopNum % 5 != 0:
            # Update our string
            setupString += entry.get() + ' '
        else:
            setupString += entry.get()
            entryData.append(setupString)

            #reset our loopstring
            setupString = ''

        # increment our loopNum
        loopNum += 1
    print(entryData)
    generateScript(entryData)

def generateScript(myList):
    fileName = ent_script_name.get()

    # Create our nested dictionary
    nested_dict = {}

    # Loop through our list
    for line in myList:
        # Specify that we want decimal with 3 percision
        decimal.getcontext().prec = 3

        # Split our line and get our parts
        parts = line.split()
        print(parts)

        state = parts[0] # Remove trailing comma
        amount = int(parts[1])
        rate = decimal.Decimal(parts[2])
        value = decimal.Decimal(parts[3])
        category = parts[4]
        print(f'Getting part 4 {parts[4]}')

        nested_dict[state] = {
            'amount': amount,     # highest amount of insurance from rate sheet
            'rate': rate,         # each add'l factor from rate sheet
            'value': value,       # factor for amount
            'category': category  # 'A' or 'H'
        }


printed out some debug statements to see the resulting dictionary
Have two python lists in which I want to add them to a nested dictionary. When I print out the resulting dictionary I see the second entry but for some reason it skips the first entry

You're using the same key ('AZ') for both entries.

Yep, that makes sense. I was just about to add a post. When I edited the key to be more unique (state and category) it seems to have fixed the issue :)

Is state+category guaranteed to be unique? If not, you can't use that either. Are you sure you want to store these things in a dict?

You can use another level of nesting: {state: {category: {...}, ...}, ...}
